# Address of array is changed when application goes in background state?

Tags: android, arrays, android-activity, background

I have one array and the address of that array is 1096589368.Now when i put the application in background state address of that array is changed and it shows me 1096584528.Most of time this happen rarely it gives me same address.Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it lead to a crash or other malfunction?

Comment: No,i am getting NULL value in array

Comment: Now that's strange. Could you try to provide us with some sample code?

Comment: Some sample code will be helpful

Comment: add Log.d where you are creating that array and you will know why it changes

Comment: can you check one thing did you declare same variable multiple times like shadowing?

Comment: no i am not using same variable

Comment: MainActivity.java

ArrayList<obj> objectList = new ArrayList<obj>();


in Background Service 
We want to getting this address.
Log.i("Application", "Address of ArrayList "+ System.identityHashCode(objectList);// Then i want this address always  be change.

Comment: I patched for this solution.I stored that array's value in sharedPreference and get everytime when i want in background state.